# Dependency in group, what test (Mann–Whitney U) to use?

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric

I have data of the following experiment: A group of 10 people performing task A six times. Another group of 10 people performing task B six times. I want to perform a statistical test to see if B is more difficult than task A, but I'm not sure what test and/or what data I should use.

I thought about using the Mann–Whitney U test as it is nonparametric. But I'm not sure what data I should use for this test. I can't compare all the 6 trials of all 10 people performing task A (so 60 trials in total) with all the 6 trials of all 10 people performing task B (again 60 trials) because then there is dependency within a group, right?

Should I compare only the last or best trials of everyone? So 10 of Task A vs 10 of Task B. Or should I compute an average for every person and compare the 10 averages for Task A with the 10 averages for Task B?

Answer (score 0):

In case you use U Mann-Whitney all mentioned ideas may be fair. You have to ask yourself, what is the most interesting/valuable information for you. We definietly don't have enough information about the structure of the tasks and of the collected data to make suggestions. 
Think what do you mean by easy/hard:

In example if you take (a) first performance; or (b) mean of the 2 first performances for each person; you can check if both tasks were equally easy to understand (that may be important if usually one person will only have 1 chance to complete task, not several as in experimental conditions).
Taking the best time may be your case if you are mostly interested in how fast it is possible to finish the task if one is trained.

Taking avarage may be an option if you don't have such specific question, but then you should check the data. Maybe all good times differ just a bit, and if one (a)lost his focus; (b)made a mistake he had to correct; time was getting veery high. In this case mean can be deceiving. Maybe better to use median then?
But then again, maybe it is important for you to evaluate, how time consuming is making mistakes and therefore how important is to be precise and fault-free (that's also a reason why task could be considered hard).

Summing up - ask youself, what do you need.

If distributions are symetrical and variances homogenous, there are no serious outliers, I guess you could go for mixed-design anova. This way you could see if:

1. Considering all 6 attempts one task takes more time than the
   other.
2. In whole sample (both task) there can be observed an effect
   of learning (further performances of each person are better).
3. There is interaction between these (for instance considering all
   attempts you can't say any task takes longer, but A took less time in
   first 3 performances, B took much less time in the latter 3, so it is easier to master it).

Comment: Thank you! That helped a lot! If there are serious outliers can I perform Friedman or Quade test to observe an effect of Learning? Also,  what are the differences between them? I read that Quade is more powerful for smaller sample sizes, are there more differences that I should be aware of?

Comment: I must admit I don't know much about Quade test. Friedman is ok, although you may want to read this: seriousstats.wordpress.com/2012/02/14/friedman For post-hoc you can use Wilcoxon signed-rank test, but remember about Bonferroni correction for multiple compariosons (to minimalize family-wise error). Divide your chosen p level (most common is 0,05) by the number of comparisons. That's why you may want to plan only certain comparisons (like only 1st vs 4th, 1st vs 6th and 4th vs 6th)